# jQuery function callback does not work in custom class/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, callback

So am a newbie to programming so excuse me if this is a novice question.  I am creating a simple wave effect to create an illusion of moving water.  I did this with a simple function in jquery and it worked fine.  I am learning OOP so my code is more organized for this project I am working on.  I created a class to handle this animation.  The animation works but it only fires once.  I need it to keep firing to create the illusion.  The function callback works the normal procedual way but it does not seem to work within the object class.  I have researched this and researched this and can not find an answer for this specific problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.  My code is below.

```
    function Waves(selector){
      this.selector = selector;
      this.animateWaves = function(forward,backward,speed){
        $(selector).velocity({translateX: forward},speed); 
        $(selector).velocity({translateX: backward},speed,animateWaves);
      };
    };
   var surfaceWaves = new Waves('#topWaves');
   surfaceWaves.animateWaves('+=40','-=40','1000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Actually, my first solution does not work because the context of the callback is the element, not the object. Here is the working code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oebx0dpq/):

```
function Waves(selector){
  this.selector = selector;
  this.animateWaves = function(forward,backward,speed){
    var self = this; 
    $(selector).velocity({translateX: forward},speed); 
      $(selector).velocity({translateX: backward}, speed, function () {
          self.animateWaves(forward,backward,speed);
      });
  };
};
var surfaceWaves = new Waves('#topWaves');
surfaceWaves.animateWaves('+=40','-=40','1000');
```

---

**Removed old code incorrect code**

Comment: when you use `this.animateWaves`, jQuery sets the context to that callback as the HTML element - so `this` doesn't refer to your JS object. The second version works because you are using the `self` variable which is a pointer to the JS object. Therefore, you have access to the `animateWaves` method.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thankyou so much. I posted that fiddle right after you post your original one.  I included it in my project and it works fine now.

Comment: Well, you need to understand scope in JavaScript. The context of a function (the value of `this` inside that function) can be explicitly set. In the case of jQuery callbacks, it is usually the DOM element that is being acted upon. The `animateWaves` method isn't tied to the DOM element, it is tied to the `Waves` JS object - so you need a reference to that object inside that callback. The reason it worked the first time is because the method wasn't called from the jQuery callback so the context was correct - but after that 1st time, the context was incorrect because it was called from jQuery.